# how to show moving character in my vb form

Tags: vb6

I am making an application in which I want to show moving character like any cartoon, say donald duck, which can guide user and provide help.
how can I do this? Is it possible in vb?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If creating a custom character isn't what you are looking for, I suggest using the [MS Agent Control 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/Merlin.aspx) to take advantage of the animated characters that ship with Windows.  I've used the Merlin character before and as I recall implementation was pretty easy.

Unfortunately I don't have the source code for that project handy, but here is someone who wrote a [quiz application using the Merlin character in VB6](http://conradsharry.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-use-ms-agent-in-vb6.html).